# Restricting Option Recognition to Single Dash (-) in Symfony Console Application

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I have a PHP script that includes an option --u (-u) for specifying a MySQL username. However, I want the script to only recognize the option when provided with a single dash (-u) and not with two dashes (--u). How can I modify my code to achieve this specificity in option recognition?

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\User;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

$application = new Application('User Upload Script', '1.0.0');


$application
    ->register('user:upload')
    ->setDescription('Uploads users from a CSV file to the database')

    ->addOption('u', 'u', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'MySQL username')
 
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {


        $username = $input->getOption('u');

}
```

The current usage allows both --u and -u to work interchangeably. I'd like to restrict it to only recognize -u as the valid option. Any suggestions on how to modify this for single-dash specificity would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looking through the [code](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/7.0/Input/InputDefinition.php), the `--u` is considered the option's name and is required, only the `-u`, which is the shortcut, is optional. I'm seeing many places in the command logic that require the name, so I don't know if it will be possible. Is there a reason you can't just call it `--user`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas
I have a code challenge as part of the hiring process for a company :-) .

Answer (score 1):

Here's the path I started down. It isn't a full answer, just something I was toying with out of pure curiosity.

When you call [`addOption()`](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/cdce5c684b2f920bb1343deecdfba356ffad83d5/Command/Command.php#L436), under the hood an [`InputOption`](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/7.0/Input/InputOption.php) is created. If you extend that class, you can override the `getName()` method. That method is used in many places, including the matching algorithm, so if you return something else, `--u` won't match:

```php
        $customInput = new class ('u', 'u', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The user') extends InputOption {

            public function getName(): string
            {
                return 'XYZ';
            }
        };

        $this->getDefinition()->addOption($customInput);
```

Running the command with `--u` will now result in `The "--u" option does not exist.`.

Unfortunately, the help text now thinks that the long version is `--XYZ` instead of `--u`, so we're kind of just punting. But, you could also override the help text and tweak there, too. That said, I think you'd just end up overriding more and more things.

Option #2, however, is pretty simple. It doesn't change the signature of the command, but if someone actually passes `--u` to the command, when we execute it we throw an error.

```php
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        if(in_array('--u',$_SERVER['argv'])){
            $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
            $io->error('The --u option is not allowed, please use -u instead');
            return Command::FAILURE;
        }

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

And instead of `$_SERVER['argv']`, you could reflect on `$input`, make `$tokens` readable and inspect that instead.

(I'm working exclusively in Symfony, not Laravel, but the general pattern should be portable over to Laravel, too.)